# How to automate sharepoint application in remote desktop using selenium

Tags: sharepoint, selenium, sharepoint-2010, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I was testing the sharepoint application in remote desktop using the selenium IDE , here IDE was recording each every case till the login credentials done in browser level ,  when the action move to remote desktop , the test cases are stopped recording in IDE. after the login actions in the browser level , the server logins also should complete to access the application.but the actions in the server level was not recording .

can any one provide solution to record the login actions in server level remote desktop for sharepoint application.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible.

You'd have to install the IDE and Firefox on the machine you are RDP'ing into.

After all, the IDE is tied into Firefox (it's a Firefox plugin), so you'd have to have it on whatever machine you are connecting to.

I would therefore suggest you look into WebDriver. It will give more flexibility over this kind of stuff.

Comment: Can i try using the webdriver install in my pc and access the application in remote desktop